# Why this array is not working properly

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, methods

I will in this method descending order number integer

```
package sortarray;

public class start {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int [] numb={10,12,8,6,2};

        sortarray(numb);
    }

    public static void sortarray(int [] input){

        int max=input[0];

        int [] sortmax=input;//i don't know how this array sortmax initialized first

        for (int i=0;i<input.length;i++)
            if(max<input[i]){
                max=input[i];

                sortmax[i]=max;//this array is not work 
            }

        for (int j=0;j<sortmax.length;j++)
            System.out.print(" "+sortmax[j]);
    }           

}
```

but into this method, (`sortmax`) is not work why?

Answer (score 1):

I understand you want to keep some kind of history of max'es?

`sortmax` is just referencing to your input array, everything you do on `sortmax` you do on `input`. You need to do this:

`int[] sortmax = new int[input.length];`

instead of `int[] sortmax = input;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the `Arrays.sort()` for this, but if the goal is to learn sorting, a brute force (slow for large vectors) sorter could look like this:

```
public void sort(int[] array){
   int[] tempArray = new int[array.length]
   int max;
   int index;
   for(int k = 0; k < array.length; k++){
     for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
       if(max < array[i]){
         max = array[i];
         index = i;
        }
     }
     tempArray[k] = array[index];
     array[index] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
   }
   array = tempArray;
}
```